# Test Automation for HTML/JS/CSS Animations

Tags: selenium, web-testing, automated-tests

Is there any open source of commercial tools available for test automation of HTML/JS/CSS animations?
Is it possible to ascertain the visual artifacts by some means of image capture and comparison ( selenium offers image grab, but its more static) quickly to ascertain a test application pass/fail

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Sikuli framework. Sikuli automates everything you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is useful when there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code.
URL - http://www.sikuli.org/

Also you can use the mix of Webdeiver and Sikuli - SikuliWebDriver. Here you can find an example of using it: http://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/SikuliWebDriver

I prefer using the Sikuli Java API and create wrapper functions around the Sikuli functions like click, type etc. 
http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/030-java-dev.html